# How to compare elements between two arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

My program has a boolean array that returns true when comparing elements between two arrays even though they aren't equal values. How do I correct my compArray method to where it returns only true when the elements are equal to each other?

```java
public static boolean compArray(double[] a, double[] b, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a.length == b.length) {
            if (a[i] == b[i]) {
                return true;
            } else return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] a = new double[5];
    double[] b = new double[5];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the amount of values: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter values for array a: ");
        a[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter values for array b: ");
        b[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    }

    boolean match = compArray(a, b, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (compArray(a, b, n)) {
            System.out.println("A " + a[i] + " B " + b[i] + " true");
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.println("A " + a[i] + " B " + b[i] + " false");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: Right now, since you have a `return` statement inside of a `for` loop, the first time that `return` gets executed the entire function will end. This means that if the first elements in the array are equal, the function will immediately return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you will compare your two double arrays for equality:

```java
public static boolean compArray (double[] a, double[] b, int n) {
    //if the arrays dont have the same length, then they are not equals
    if (a.length != b.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            //if one element at array a is different than the other at array b, 
            //at the same index, then the arrays are not equals
            if (a[i] != b[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    //otherwise, the two arrays are equals
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. There's a library function for that:

```
public static boolean compArray(double[] a, double[] b, int n) {
     return Arrays.equals(a, 0, n, b, 0, n);
}
```

See [`Arrays.equals​(double[] a, int aFromIndex, int aToIndex, double[] b, int bFromIndex, int bToIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(double%5B%5D,int,int,double%5B%5D,int,int))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just compare 2 elements in the array, you don't need a function for that. You are passing in `n`, but you could just check that `a[n] == b[n]`. I'm assuming what you want is a function that compares the whole arrays.

Instead of returning `true` when the first elements are equal and trying to return `false` at the end, scan the entire array looking for elements that are NOT equal. As soon as you reach a pair that is NOT equal, you know the arrays are not equal and you can return `false`. If none of the elements are NOT equal, then the elements are all equal and you can return `true`.

```java
public static boolean compArray (double[] a, double[] b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if (a.length == b.length) {
            if (a[i] != b[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You may want to look into the difference between `break` and `return`.

Another thing you can do is move the length check outside the loop, like this:

```java
public static boolean compArray (double[] a, double[] b)
{
    // immediately exit if the lengths are not equal
    if (a.length != b.length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // loop through and exit once an unequal pair is found
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
        {
            // returns from the whole function, not just the for loop
            return false;
        }
    }

    // if this code is reached, the lengths must have been equal and there were no pairs that didn't match, so the arrays must be completely equal
    return true;
}
```

This makes the code more readable and makes it so the length condition doesn't need to be checked on every loop iteration -- just once at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing "n" as the index to compare, when you should be passing "i". You can simplify the method as well since you have a for-loop in your main function:

```
public static boolean compArray (double[] a, double[] b, int i)
  {
    if(a[i] == b[i]){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

in Main...

```
for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
      if (compArray(a, b, i))
```

Sample Input:
2
1
1
3
4

Sample Output: A 1.0 B 1.0 true, B 3.0 B 4.0 false